# Sending A File Via A Contact Form In HTML5 And PHP

Tags: php, html

before I ask my question please allow me to say that I am not a php developer currently. I have a little experience with PHP but my background is mainly with HTML5, CSS3, SASS, JS, Jquery, Basic PHP.

With that in mind here is my problem. Currently I have a html5 based form which I am using to parse a name and recipient email field + attach a document.

I have the email sending and the document, however regardless of which doc type I send it comes through as a txt file and the file itself is always empty. So my question is why? / What Am I Doing wrong?

I know I need to do other things to the form i.e. validation, captcha etc but at this stage all I want is to send the complete file.

Below Is what I have so far, please excuse any formatting issues:

**HTML5**

```
<form role="form" action="addDocument.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <!-- file browse and upload-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" name="file" class="file">
        <div class="input-group col-xs-12">

            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-file-image-o"></i></span>                                       
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" disabled placeholder="Upload Image"> 

            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="browse btn btn-primary input-lg" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Browse</button>
            </span>
        </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="c-form-1-name">Name</label>
        <input id="c-form-1-name" class="c-form-1-name form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name..." type="text">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="c-form-1-email">Recipient Email</label>
        <input id="c-form-1-email" class="c-form-1-email form-control" name="remail" placeholder="Recipient Email..." type="text">
   </div>       
   <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Send</button> </form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$senderEmail = '<demo@mydomain.co.uk>'; 
$recipientEmail = filterInput($_POST['remail']); 
$message = 'You have been sent an electronic document via the Demo';
$subject = 'Demo';

echo $senderEmail.$recipientEmail.$message.$subject;
if(sendEmailWithAttachments($recipientEmail,$senderEmail,$subject,$message))
{
    echo "Email sent successfully!";
}
else
{
    echo "Failed to send the email...";
}

function filterInput($data)
{
     $data = trim($data);
     $data = stripslashes($data);
     $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
     return $data;
}
function sendEmailWithAttachments($recipientEmail,$senderEmail,$subject,$message){


    if(isset($_FILES)) {

echo "iamhere";
        $allowedExtensions = array("pdf","doc","docx","gif","jpeg","jpg","JPG","png","PNG","rtf","txt","xml");

        $files = array();
        foreach($_FILES as $name=>$file) {
            //die("file size: ".$file['size']);
            if($file['size']>=5242880)//5mb
            {
                $fileSize=$file['size'];
                return false;
            }
            $file_name = $file['name']; 
            $temp_name = $file['tmp_name'];
            $file_type = $file['type'];
            $path_parts = pathinfo($file_name);
            $ext = $path_parts['extension'];
            if(!in_array($ext,$allowedExtensions)) {
                return false;
                die("File $file_name has the extensions $ext which is not allowed");
            }

            //move the file to the server, cannot be skipped
            $server_file="/tmp/$path_parts[basename]";
            move_uploaded_file($temp_name,$server_file);
            array_push($files,$server_file);
            //array_push($files,$temp_name);
        }

        // email fields
        $headers = "From: $senderEmail";


        // boundary 
        $semi_rand = md5(time()); 
        $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 

        // headers for attachment 
        $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

        // multipart boundary 
        $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n"; 
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

        // preparing attachments
        for($x=0;$x<count($files);$x++){
            $file = fopen($files[$x],"rb");
            $data = fread($file,filesize($files[$x]));
            fclose($file);
            $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
            $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$files[$x]\"\n" . 
            "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$files[$x]\"\n" . 
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
            $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
        }

        // send
        return @mail($recipientEmail, $subject, $message, $headers);

    }
}
```

Comment: You should really not be using PHP’s `mail` to send such emails - the structure of those is complex, and it is easy to mess things up. Use a script such as PHPMailer or Swift Mailer for such purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to form if you want to post any file/image

from

```
<form role="form" action="addDocument.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
```

to

```
<form role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="addDocument.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
```

Comment: Thanks this really helped and everything now works,.... however I am still receiving a blank .txt file a long with the attached document. Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: once print files array before // preparing attachments and check what data your getting...if possible paste here

Comment: Sorry Kranthi, perhaps I didn't explain well. I am now receiving the complete document of tested types such as word,pdf,img etc. The documents are complete with all expected data. 

However I receive an additional blank txt file also

Comment: ok so i printed out the array and all i get is application/msword. 
I tested with a word document as to test something that isnt a .txt file. 

Strange